# Extract some numbers and decimals from a string

Tags: c#, wpf, regex, vb.net

I have a string:

```
"   a.1.2.3 #4567   "
```

and I want to reduce that to just "1.2.3".

Currently using Substring() and Remove(), but that breaks if there ends up being more numbers after the pound sign.

What's the best way to go about doing this? I've read a bunch of questions on regex & string.split, but I can't get anything I try to work in VB.net. Would I have to do a match then replace using the match result?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please include an explanation that helps us see on what basis "1.2.3" is the correct output from the original string?

Comment: What exactly did you try? Getting `number.number.number` out of that string using regex doesn't seem too hard?

Comment: @Tormod None of the alphanumerics in that string are literal, it could be "z.4.4.4 #666". All I'm trying to get is d\.\d\.\d from the original string. Not sure if that answers your question, it's very late here.

Comment: @ronald and what's wrong with just using `\d\.\d\.\d` in a `Match`?

Comment: @m.buettner I tried that using the example [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-match-vbnet) as a basis, but it was returning an empty value for some reason.

Comment: @ronald did you forget the leading backslash (like in your comment)?

Comment: @m.buettner That must've been it. Sriram Sakthivel's solution works fine. Trying to code while exhausted is probably a terrible idea. heh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
string input = "   a.1.2.3 #4567   ";
int poundIndex = input.IndexOf("#");
if(poundIndex >= 0)
{
    string relevantPart = input.Substring(0, poundIndex).Trim();
    IEnumerable<Char> numPart = relevantPart.SkipWhile(c => !Char.IsDigit(c));
    string result = new string(numPart.ToArray());
}
```

<kbd>**[Demo](http://ideone.com/FnKAok)**</kbd>

Comment: +1 because the demo bit is brilliant (the code is also fine) :)

Comment: Works great. Thanks again for taking the time to write that out.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
String[] splited = split("#");
String output = splited[0].subString(2); // 1 is the index of the "." after "a" considering there are no blank spaces before it..
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is regex way of doing it

```
 string input = "   a.1.2.3 #4567   ";
 Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\d\.)+\d");
 var match = regex.Match(input);
 if(match.Success)
 {
     string output = match.Groups[0].Value;//"1.2.3"
     //Or
     string output = match.Value;//"1.2.3"
 }
```

Comment: Or just `match.Value`.

Comment: Your solution works good too, thanks. Not sure what the best one is so I marked the first one I tried as accepted. If you guys feel a better choice should be picked let me know.

Comment: My solution should work even when there is no `#` character in the string, where as other solutions fail to do so, It is your call to pick the one based on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If the pound sign is the most relevant bit, rely on `Split`. Sample VB.NET code:

```
Dim inputString As String = "   a.1.2.3 #4567  "
If (inputString.Contains("#")) Then
    Dim firstBit As String = inputString.Split("#")(0).Trim()
    Dim headingToRemove As String = "a."
    Dim result As String = firstBit.Substring(headingToRemove.Length, firstBit.Length - headingToRemove.Length)
End If
```

As far as this is a multi-language question, here comes the translation to C#:

```
string inputString = "   a.1.2.3 #4567  ";
if (inputString.Contains("#"))
{
    string firstBit = inputString.Split('#')[0].Trim();
    string headingToRemove = "a.";
    string result = firstBit.Substring(headingToRemove.Length, firstBit.Length - headingToRemove.Length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess another way using unrolled

```
 \d+ (?: \. \d+ )+
```

Comment: I would suggest giving the OP a little more detail on how he would use your answer. A code snippet would be helpful.

Comment: I'm guessing I'd get the same result as I would with Sriram's expression, except it would be able to match and return, say "11.22.3.444444", instead of just "1.2.3"?